# How to enumerate through Autocad Entities without using Autocad.Interop?

Tags: c#, autocad, autocad-plugin, objectarx

I'd like to enumerate all entities in an Autocad Drawing, but not using `Autocad.Interop` reference.

With Interop I could just pick:

```
IAcadApplication App = (IAcadApplication)Application.AcadApplication;
IAcadDocument Doc = App.ActiveDocument;

foreach (IAcadEntity Ent in Doc.ModelSpace) // or paperspace, or any IAcadBlock
```

But with the `Object Arx` references I can only find tutorials to get entities using transactions in a database, taking objects by ID. I think that's really boring stuff to slow down the works.

Answer (score 2):

That's the way we do it.  You have either the Interop code, or some fashion of objectid iteration.

Here's a good article from the Dev Network: http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/05/whats-the-best-way-to-iterate-through-an-entire-database.html

If you are going to work with C#, I recommend just biting the bullet, and moving on to use transactions and such, there is really no way around it.